# Benefit of defining service at ngOnInit rather at Constructor in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, ngoninit

I am aware some of the facts where `ngOnInit()` and constructor differ. also I have come across many examples where services are defined at `ngOnInit()` method rather in a constructor and vice-versa.

But using services at constructor level is not prohibited by Angular. If such is the case what benefit it drives in doing so when compared to defining services at `ngOInit()`?

Example:

```
 export class App implements OnInit{

 constructor(private userService: UserService){
     userService.getDetails();
 }

 ngOnInit(){
    userService.getDetails(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ngOnInit()` hook is one of the Angular lifecycle hooks.
The example you provided works as you noticed, but it is limited because you can't access any `@Input()` variable in the constructor. So your pattern won't work if you want to pass a parameter to your service function, that comes from an `@Input()` variable.
As a good practice, always use `ngOnInit()` instead of the constructor for your components initializations because everything will always work fine, while the constructor pattern will not work for every use case.